# Available fonts in .net are showing only 6 fonts

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, fonts

When I list available fonts under Windows 7 VS2010 I get the following result:

> Buxton Sketch
>   Guttman Vilna
>   Marlett
>   Microsoft New Tai Lue
>   Monotype Hadassah
>   Segoe Marker

When I select a font in the font dialog of my app and click OK I get an Exception:

> Only TrueType fonts are supported

What can I do to restore all fonts? Why is this happening?

Comment: Your machine is probably broken.  You'll need the Geek Squad, not a programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue 2 days ago, I tried to instal a new font I downloaded. 
I do not know how to restore all fonts, but if you right click on a font in windows 7 you can press Install, that did the job for me and installed it correct.